# VAR model selection in R

Tags: r, time-series, var

I have employed the automatic selection procedure which suggest VAR(2).

```
> VARselect(dlogdata,lag.max=10,type="const")
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     8      2      2      4
```

However, when checking for white noise, there are significant auto-correlations.

[image: VAR(2)]

So, I have been increasing the order of the VAR model, until there are no significant auto correlations. I came to VAR(6):

[image: VAR(6)]

This seems like a very not parsimonious model.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. How should I choose the best model? How can I compare the goodness of fit of VAR model with different order?
2. How can I validate the model?

Comment: This question might get better responses on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in serially correlated errors you must perform a jointed serial test for all the model. Considering the next example, using `Canada` data set, only considering the first 2 variable in data, let assume optimal lag is 3, then we have:

```r
library(vars)
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: strucchange
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Loading required package: sandwich
#> Loading required package: urca
#> Loading required package: lmtest
library(magrittr)
data("Canada")
model <- VAR(Canada[,1:2],3)
```

Then perform the Portmanteau test

```
serial.test(model)
#> 
#>  Portmanteau Test (asymptotic)
#> 
#> data:  Residuals of VAR object model
#> Chi-squared = 35.009, df = 52, p-value = 0.966
```

We can check residuals:

```
plot(serial.test(model))
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

`vars::VARselect()` only select the best model based on information criteria (IC), is has nothing to do with serial correlated problem. Model selected based in AIC, for example, only guaranteed that your error are minimal.